# Confused how the order of recursion function works when achieve a preorder traversal in javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree, preorder

I used the code below to get the pre-order traversal. I have read that how pre-order works, it traversals the binary tree as the order: root-left-right. But my question is why this recursion function can give output as the preorder? how it works inside?

```
var tree = {
"id": 0,
"name": "root",
"left": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Simon",
    "left": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Carl",
        "left": {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Lee",
            "left": {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "Fate"
            }
        },
        "right": {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Annie",
            "left": {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "Saber"
            }
        }
    },
    "right": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Tony",
        "left": {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Candy"
        }
    }
},
"right": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "right",
    "left": {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Carl",
    },
    "right": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Carl",
        "right": {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Kai"
            }        
        }
    }
}

function getListWithDLR() {
    var arr=[];
    function DLR(obj){
        if(obj){
            arr.push(obj.name);
            DLR(obj.left);
            DLR(obj.right);
          }
     }
     DLR(tree);
     console.log(arr);
    }
getListWithDLR();
```

the output is :0: "root"
1: "Simon"
2: "Carl"
3: "Lee"
4: "Fate"
5: "Annie"
6: "Saber"
7: "Tony"
8: "Candy"
9: "right"
10: "Carl"
11: "Carl"
12: "Kai"

in my understanding it should run like this:

```
    function DLR(tree){
    if(tree){
        arr.push(tree.name);
        DLR(tree.left); //push the tree.left.name to arr
        DLR(tree.right);//push the tree.right.name to arr
      }
 }
```

so after first time call the function,the arr should like[root,tree.left.name,tree.right.name]. but the finall output actual followed the preorder. 
Anyone can help explain the rules behind this function?

Comment: How does "*the final output actually followed the preorder*"? What is "the preorder"? Oh, you mean the oder in the object literal. Got it.

Comment: `DLR` returns only after it finishes processing an entire branch which means that `DLR(tree.right)` is called only after the entire left branch has been processed.

Answer (score 0):

It goes like this:

1. The first call is with object *tree*, so the name "root" is pushed to *arr* and DLR is called again with *tree.left*
2. On this call, the name "Simon" is pushed to *arr* and DLR is called again with *Simon.left*
3. On this call, the name "Carl" is pushed to *arr* and DLR is called again with *Carl.left*
4. On this call, the name "Lee" is pushed to *arr* and DLR is called again with *Lee.left*
5. On this call, "Fate" is pushed to *arr* and DLR is called again with *Fate.left*. Since there is no *Fate.left* or *right*, nothing happens
6. Now the call drops to *Fate.right*, but there's no *Fate.right* either so nothing happens
7. Now DLR is called with *Lee.right*, there isn't one so nothing happens.
8. Now DLR is called with *Carl.right*
9. On this call, the name "Annie" is pushed to *arr* and DLR is called again with *Annie.left*
10. On this call, the name "Saber" is pushed to *arr* and DLR is called again with *Saber.left*
11. There is no *Saber.left* or *Saber.right* so nothing happens
12. Now DLR is called with *Simon.right*
13. On this call, the name "Tony" is pushed to *arr* and DLR is called again with *Tony.left*
14. And so on…

I guess you can summarise it as doing all of a left branch, then backs up to the most recent previous right branch and goes down its left branch, then back up to the most recent previous right, etc.